# Is there a faster way to find any name in namesArray?

Tags: javascript

Can I find a required name without loop through each array item? 
Is there any faster way to do the same assuming that I have a very big array length, because if I have an array of 10000 items and the name doesn't exist in it, it will be a waste of time and assuming that we don't have inclouds function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function binarySearch(names, requiredName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
      if (names[i] === requiredName) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  console.log(binarySearch(['ola', 'amer', 'anwar', 'mamon'], 'hadeel'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [Array#includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: for searching you have to use this only  there is no option for an array to use a lamda expression.

Comment: but you can use a trick way to do this ..but that is not a good way  but it will give you the result in one line

Comment: no if you want to do that then just

Comment: convert your array to string then use Contains your name  it will give you the a boolean value if it is there it will give you true or flase

Comment: @imdisney No need to convert to string and then check. And the doc for [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#String.prototype.contains)

Comment: if he want to do fast then it can happen with it i have tried as well so dont worry

Comment: The question has been asked before.

Comment: Instead of using an array, one can use an object for name lookup. One can also use `Map` or `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Array#includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function like this.

```
names.includes(requiredName)
```

If you want to know exactly WHERE the item is located you need to iterate like you already did.

Comment: Flag as duplicate.

Comment: *If you want to know exactly WHERE the item is located* for this can use `indexOf`

Comment: This only works if the name is unique, otherwise it just gives the Index of the first occurance.    BTW there is Nö duplicate

Comment: assume that theirs no includes or indexOf

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
var array = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
var search = "foo"; 

// using the ES6 some function
var includes = array.some(val => val == search);
console.log(includes);

// using the find function
var found = array.find(val => val == search);
console.log(!!found); // or found != null
```

but the simplest way is indexOf or includes (but doens't have full browser support yet)